# How can I make the input group addon to be visible only on hover, while preserving the width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make the input group addon to be visible only on hover?
While preserving the width of the input line with addon and without it.
I would like to do this juts with css magic if it is possible.

[image]

Comment: May be its possible, could you please create a fiddle? I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works so far:

.show-on-hover{
  display: none;
}

.row:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: table-cell;
}

However I am not sure if it is a professional solution so a professional advice/review is required please.